# Migrating SDO_JOIN to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a query in Oracle to select polygons from `my_polygon_table` that interact or reside inside of a single polygon residing in `border_table`:

```
Select t1.*, t2.*, sdo_geom.sdo_intersection(t1.geoloc, t2.geom, 2 ) as genericgeo From      ( sdo_join ('my_border_table', 'geoloc', 'my_polygon_table', 'geom', 'mask=ANYINTERACT' ) ) j,
 my_border_table t1,my_polygon_table t2 
 Where 
 (j.rowId1 = t1.rowId and j.rowId2 = t2.rowId) and (t1.geoloc.sdo_gtype = 2003 or t1.geoloc.sdo_gtype = 2007) and (t2.geom.sdo_gtype = 2003 or t2.geom.sdo_gtype = 2007)
```

So far I've installed geometry with `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` and copied tables. When I run a query in pgAdmin I get

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "table"
LINE 2: ...ntersection(t1.geoloc, t2.geom, 2 ) as genericgeo From table
                                                                  ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 129
```

How to do the same thing with PostgreSQL?

Comment: @CL Query fails because ther is no `sdo_join` in PostGIS.  `table` has no effect because it selects `from sdo_join(/*..*/) j`. I removed keyword `table` to avoid confusion. Oracle still works, PostGIS still fails.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL/PostGIS implement the SQL/MM specification, so just write it in proper SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_border_table  t1
JOIN my_polygon_table t2 ON ST_Intersects(t1.geoloc, t2.geom)
WHERE ST_Dimension(t1.geoloc) = 2
  AND ST_Dimension(t2.geom  ) = 2;

-- or:
--     ST_GeometryType(t1.geoloc) IN ('ST_Polygon', 'ST_MultiPolygon')
-- AND ST_GeometryType(t2.geom  ) IN ('ST_Polygon', 'ST_MultiPolygon')
```